# django rest framework serializer - doesn't return empty list field

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a serializer for a model that contains JsonField. I want to always return specific fields, even when they are not found within the jsonField.
When calling 'get' - it does return all fields in the serializer, but when calling 'update', it returns the instance with the updated fields and `allow_null=True`, so `default=list` field that wasn't update - would not return in the response. The question is how can I still return all serializer fields in response, including the `default=list` fields, even when they weren't updated and not exist?

this is the serializer -

```
class ObjectsListSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    days = serializers.IntegerField(allow_null=True, source='objects_list.days')
    user_list = serializers.ListField(child=serializers.CharField(), default=list, allow_empty=True, required=False, source='objects_list.user_list')
    manager = serializers.CharField(allow_null=True, source='objects_list.manager')

    def update(instance, validated_data):
                if 'objects_list' in validated_data:
        for attr, value in validated_data['objects_list'].items():
            instance.objects_list[attr] = value
        instance.save()

        return instance
```

As mentioned, when sending 'get' request, even when 'objects_list' is empty, I would get

```
days=None
user_list=[]
manager=None
```

in the response

But when user_list doesn't exist and I'm updating other field ('days' for example), 'user_list' will not exist in the response.
Any idea how can I still return the empty list when it doesn't exist?

Comment: Please show your views for get and update

Comment: I'm using the built in `mixins.UpdateModelMixin`. didn't change it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand you're using a partial update. For partial update serializers skip a field from response if it failed to retreive it (can see in the source code [here](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/fields.py#L503)). Apparantly it fails to retreive because `objects_list` is `None`, so `objects_list.user_list` raises `AttributeError`.

So, to make it work as you want you should manually return fully serialized data in your view:

```py
def partial_update(self, request, pk=None):
  partial_serializer = self.get_serializer(self.get_object(), data=request.data, partial=True)
  partial_serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
  instance = partial_serializer.save()
  # Saved, now return all attributes (not using partial=True here):
  return Response(self.get_serializer(instance).data)
```

Comment: indeed I'm using partial update. Will try that and update here. Thanks